# Compiling / installing shotdetect for OS X

Tags: macos, terminal, video, homebrew, automation

I would like to find scene changes in a video with this command line tool:

> [Shotdetect](https://github.com/johmathe/Shotdetect) is a free software (LGPL) which detects shots and scenes
>   from a video.

Dependencies are:

> sudo apt-get install libavdevice-dev libavformat-dev
>   libgd2-noxpm libgd2-noxpm-dev

What I did already:

- `git clone https://github.com/johmathe/Shotdetect.git`
- `mkdir -p build; cd build; cmake -D USE_WXWIDGETS:BOOL=OFF ..`

I get this error message ([full output](http://pastebin.com/uTTsqaC9)):

```
CMake Error at cmake/FindGD.cmake:112 (MESSAGE):
  Could not find GD library
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:85 (FIND_PACKAGE)
```

I have [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) installed, but I do not know how to map the dependencies mentioned above to a `brew install ...` command.

**Is homebrew the way to go? If so, what would be the "install" command?**

PS. I am on OS X 10.8.5 with Xcode 5.0.2 and Xcode Command Line Tools installed.

Comment: You are missing dependencies(listed in the apt-get install command). Check if you can install them via homebrew, if not you have to compile them by yourself and after that compile shotdetect.

Comment: libavdevice and libavformat are a part of ffmpeg, so do brew install ffmpeg if it warns about that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### How to compile

#### Easy version (late 2015)

- make sure you have homebrew installed
- install dependencies
- download source code:
  `git clone https://github.com/johmathe/Shotdetect.git`
  `cd Shotdetect`
- run install script: `./compile.sh all`
- find the binary "shotdetect-cmd" in the `build` directory.
- for details, check **How to use** section below

#### Old version (up to late 2015)

```bash
brew install gd    # ... obviously, http://brew.sh is needed for this!
git clone https://github.com/johmathe/Shotdetect.git
cd Shotdetect
```

I found XML output was broken as of 2014-02-11, so I applied these two patches. This might be a hack:

```bash
curl https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/johmathe/Shotdetect/pull/8.patch | git apply
curl https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/johmathe/Shotdetect/pull/9.patch | git apply
```

Finally:

```bash
mkdir -p build; cd build
cmake -D USE_WXWIDGETS:BOOL=OFF ..    # make sure you include the two dots! :)
make
```

The resulting binary is `shotdetect-cmd`.

### How to use

Here is a sample command that worked for me:

`./shotdetect-cmd -i test.mp4 -o outputDir  -s 60 -w -v -f -l -m -r -a FOO`

Flags explained:

```
-i file      : input file path
-o path      : output path (MUST exist already)
-a id        : (required!) movie ID (alphanumeric, creates subfolder in output path)
-s threshold : threshold (optional, default=75, 60 is recommended in the docs(??))

-w           : generate xml of audio
-v           : generate xml of video infos

-m           : generate the thumbnail images
-r           : generate the images in native resolution

-f           : generate 1st image for each shot  ( -m or/and -r flags must be set)
-l           : generate last image for each shot ( -m or/and -r flags must be set)
```

### Troubleshooting

On a second install in spring of 2015, shotdetect complained:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libtiff.5.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libgd.3.dylib
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

I could fix this with `brew reinstall libtiff`.

Comment: This works and goes through the entire process but I get an error at the end. It creates most of the output but not the results.xml which is the most important one. GD Error: gd-png: fatal libpng error: Wrote palette index exceeding num_palette
GD Warning: gd-png error: setjmp returns error condition
I/O error : No such file or directory
I/O error : No such file or directory